# How does cnosdb ensure data consistency during drop?

Tags: cnosdb

In cnosdb, the meta node stores metadata and the data node stores actual data. So, when dropping a database or tenant, what is the order of dropping metadata and actual data? How to ensure consistency when dropping one of them fails? I would like to know more about the technical details. Looking forward to your answer.